# Remove rows where two columns contain partial string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, orders and product. I want to filter orders column having two(out of many - key and product code) attributes from product column.

have tried pandas string but it does nothing.

```
orders = df_ipp_h_complex_f[df_ipp_h_complex_f['PRODUCT'].str.contains(("1666-K030-V001|1666-K037-V001|1666-K020-V002")) & df_ipp_h_complex['PRODUCT'].str.contains("MC")]
```

expected is to get df containing orders not having both product key and code.

actually it is giving 0 as filter row count

For example, I'd like the following code to return row1, row2 and row4 as output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': ['h', 'hxx', 'gxx', 'bxx'], 
    'b':['ac', 'xxz', 'bc', 'xxy']})

df[df['b'].str.contains('a') & df['b'].str.contains('xx')]
```

Comment: `orders = df_ipp_h_complex_f.loc[~(df_ipp_h_complex_f['PRODUCT'].str.contains(("1666-K030-V001|1666-K037-V001|1666-K020-V002"))) & (df_ipp_h_complex['PRODUCT'].str.contains("MC"))]`

Comment: thanks for the code but this gives only ordernos which has 'mc as value in product column. but i want only those orders in my order column which has both product key(1666-K037-V001) and product code(MC). so for every unique order(say order1) i will get two rows - order1+key and order1+code. more like - pick a order no and if it has both key and code associated with it keep in selection else discard.

Comment: @Raghav - If you want to clarify your question, please do so by editing it, and not (just) in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried copying your code into a toy example (with simpler names, so it's easier to read...), and it seems to work (in `pandas` version 0.21.1).
I'll post this code example, see if you can find anything different. Hope this helps in some way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': ['h', 'hxx', 'gxx', 'bxx'], 
                             'b':['a', 'bxx', 'b', 'cxx'],
                            'c': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']})
df[df['a'].str.contains('xx') & df['b'].str.contains('xx')]
```

Comment: it works when column are different but not working when two condition in same column. so when code is changed to : df[df['a'].str.contains('xx') & df['a'].str.contains('h')] - this fails

Comment: You have to be more clear in your comments. What do you mean by 'this fails'? When I run it, I get the expected result - only the second line is kept. Are you getting the same result? If so, is it not the desired result?

Comment: sorry if been a little unclear but what i meant was: your code runs wells that is df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': ['h', 'hxx', 'gxx', 'bxx'], 
                             'b':['a', 'bxx', 'b', 'cxx'],
                            'c': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']})
df[df['a'].str.contains('xx') & df['b'].str.contains('xx')] however when  i change the code to df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': ['h', 'hxx', 'gxx', 'bxx'], 
                             'b':['ac', 'xxz', 'bc', 'xxy']})
df[df['b'].str.contains('a') & df['b'].str.contains('xx')] which give the output as row1, row2 and row4.

Comment: Works fine on my side. The change that you did results in an empty output, as it should - there is no row in which column 'b' contains both 'a' and 'xx', so no rows satisfy the condition, and nothing is returned.

[Edited]: Wait - from your example, I have to ask - maybe you mean 'or' instead of 'and' (the "&" sign)?

Comment: @ Mushkin, a bit late to reply but thanks for pointing in right direction. I indeed solved the problem by using or(|) operator rather than &. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer, so they'll know the question is answered.